# Expression Node Result in different type?

Tags: animation-nodes

I am going through the Expression node and thinking of the possibility. While with INPUT, I can keep adding all kind of variables with different type, I am curious about whether OUTPUT RESULT can be of any other arbitrary output? I believe it is only output Float and single value?

I use this formula to try:
https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_1/mathutils.noise.html

Or is it better if I use Script Node?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The expression node can output any type you want. When you click on the little gear icon you can also change the socket type of the output.

However not all python modules can be used by default. To use other modules like `mathutils` you have to enable them before. This can be done in the advanced settings like in the image below.

[image]